# Add Facebook log-in button

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

Edicy.com doesn't support php and I was wondering what html code to add to enable Facebook log-in that doesn't require php.

I'm also wondering if I need to sign up as developer and get an ID in Facebook to be able to use the code.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. You need to register as a developer [here](http://developers.facebook.com) (free of course).
2. Then create an app from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/apps). And configure the appropriate settings.
3. This will get you an app id, which is used in the code
4. Without PHP, yes of course, integrating the [javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) is too simple.
5. Integrate the facebook login from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/) - trust me too simple!

Rest, if you find any difficulty you'll find its solution here in stack!

I hope that helps. Good luck!